# How to get all incoming calls for all users in UCMA with an Application Endpoint

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I try to register a handler for incoming calls for all Lync Users. The problem is I cannot store all the Credentials that are needed when using a UserEndpoint. At the moment I have managed to retrieve all Lync Users and also their online state with a hard coded service UserEndpoint.

As I already figured out, you cannot listen for incoming calls with an ApplicationEndpoint, so do I need a UserEndpoint for every Lync User? I read somewhere that it is possible to create a UserEndpoint without Credentials in a trusted Application.

In theory I already created a trusted application relationship between the Lync Front End Server and the Application Server and also registered the TrustedApplicationEndpoint. I just can't be sure if it is really working as I do not get a different result when changing the trustedapplicationname or any of the other settings.

Is there another way to solve this problem?
 If not what do I have to do to listen for all incoming Calls?

Comment: When you say you want to "listen for incoming calls" do you mean calls to the UCMA application (application endpoint) or all calls on the network.  I ask as I have the solution for both scenarios.

Comment: All calls in the network (all calls for all users in the lync domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to register for incoming calls on an `ApplicationEndpoint`, but it will listen only to calls directed to it, not to other users. An application endpoint has it's own SIP address.

You can deal with your problems in multiple ways. A lot depends on what you want to do with "listening to all incoming calls".

The route you have chosen is to create a `UserEndpoint` for each user. If you have a trusted application already set up, you can use its `CollaborationPlatform` to create new user endpoints. The idea of a "*trusted*" application is that it is allowed to impersonate everyone and create endpoints on their behalf, without having each users' credentials.

Some important things to think about for this solution:

- Creating an endpoint for every user could mean creating and managing a lot of endpoints.
- Users will be shown as online (or away/busy/etc) whether they really are or not, because you created an active endpoint for them.
- This will not catch calls to non-existing addresses (might not be a real problem).

The second option is to use `MSPL` to change the routing of incoming calls. You can redirect calls to the SIP address of your `ApplicationEndpoint`, and you will need only 1 endpoint and one call listener. Some more info and details on this method can be found here: [Rerouting requests to a UCMA application with MSPL](http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/09/04/rerouting-requests-ucma-application-mspl/).

As said before, a lot depends on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I would recommend the MSPL option for your problem of listening to all the calls on the network Kirschi.

Comment: I already tested MSPL a little bit as I was stuck on this problem. I didn't want to use it at first as it seemed quite complicated and not very well documented. But I will use it now after I saw all the problems with UCMA. Thanks!

Comment: MSPL Documentation and examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439164%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I chose MSPL. Now I face another problem @WillemDuncan that is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632889/lync-mspl-application-not-being-trusted) if you would be so nice to help me once again :)