# Establish UserEndpoint without Credentials in UCMA 4

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

How can I establish a UserEndpoint without Credentials? I read somewhere that it should be possible if the Application/ApplicationServer is trusted by the Lync Server. This is the case, but it does not seem to work. I always get the Exception

> No matching credential found for the realm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist set-up CollaborationPlatform using `ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings`:

```
ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings settings = new ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings("UCMA 4", _appID);
CollaborationPlatform  _collabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(settings);
_collabPlatform.RegisterForApplicationEndpointSettings(this.Platform_ApplicationEndpointOwnerDiscovered);
// Initialize and start-up the platform.
_collabPlatform.BeginStartup(EndPlatformStartup, _collabPlatform);
```

Then Set-up your application endpoint in `Platform_ApplicationEndpointOwnerDiscovered` callback method. then once it all done you can call this method and set-up  UserEndpoint without credentials:

```
Use this method to create UserEndpoint
private UserEndpoint CreateUserEndpoint(CollaborationPlatform  _collabPlatform, String _SIP)
{
    try
    {
        UserEndpointSettings _settings = new UserEndpointSettings(_SIP, _serverFqdn);
        _settings.SupportedMimePartContentTypes = new ContentType[] { new ContentType("text/html"), new ContentType("text/plain") };
        _settings.AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled = true;
        UserEndpoint _userEndpoint = new UserEndpoint(_collabPlatform, _settings);
        _userEndpoint.EndEstablish(_userEndpoint.BeginEstablish(null, null));

        return _userEndpoint;
    }
    catch (Exception exx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + _SIP + "CreateUserEndpoint : " + exx);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about establishing a user endpoint without a credential but you can definitely impersonate one on an established conversation if that helps.

Just checkout the Impersonate method on the conversation class.

Comment: Problem is I need to solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234704/how-to-get-all-incoming-calls-for-all-users-in-ucma-with-an-application-endpoint?rq=1) problem. I need to get all incoming calls for a (all) user, not creating a new conversation. So I guess I need a UserEndpoint for this?

Comment: Ok, think I can help and have posted a comment in your original thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impersonate you need an application endpoint.

Use an application end point to create a Conversation object and ...

`Conversation conversation = new Conversation(_appEndpoint);
 conversation.Impersonate("sip:something@something.com", "phoneUri, "Display Name");`

Comment: Well this way I create a specific Conversation on behalf of someone else... It isn't possible to receive all incoming calls for this user this way, is it?

Comment: No, to receive incoming calls for a user you need to create a `UserEndpoint`. The `ApplicationEndpoint` only receives calls for it's own endpoint uri.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh538496(v=office.14).aspx)

```
   userEndpointSettings = new UserEndpointSettings(_userURI, _serverFqdn);

            if (!_useSuppliedCredentials)
            {
                _credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_userName, _userPassword, _userDomain);
                userEndpointSettings.Credential = _credential;
            }
            else
            {
                userEndpointSettings.Credential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }
```

_userURI need to match the current logged-in user sip:user@blabla.com