# Lync MSPL Application not being trusted

Tags: c#, lync

I have a MSPL script that is "embedded" into a C# Application. running the MSPL Script directly on the Front End works fine but the deployment process is pretty complicated and lengthy. When I try the same with the C# App on the Front End I always get the following Exception

> > Application Not Authorized
> >
> > > Inner Exception: Queue could not be created.

This is my Code:

```
// Handler for MSPL Callbacks
LyncSIPHandler serverApplication = new LyncSIPHandler();

// Load the app manifest from a file.
ApplicationManifest manifest = ApplicationManifest.CreateFromFile("msplscript.am");
try {
    manifest.Compile();
    Util.Log(manifest.ApplicationUri);
}
catch (CompilerErrorException ex) {
    Util.Log("#2 MSPL Compile: " + ex.Message);
}

ServerAgent agent = null;
try {
    agent = new ServerAgent(serverApplication, manifest);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Util.Log("#3 " + ex.Message);
}
```

The Exception is thrown when I try to create the `ServerAgent` with the compiled Script.
The output of Log#1 (manifest.ApplicationUri) is `[...URL...]/LyncToolApp`. When I run `Get-CSServerApplication` on the Server (Lync 2013) I get the following output

```
Identity   : Service:Registrar:[...server...]/LyncToolApp
Priority   : 6
Uri        : [...url...]/LyncToolApp
Name       : LyncToolApp
Enabled    : True
Critical   : False
ScriptName :
Script     :
```

What have I missed to make the App run?

Note: I was following [this MSPL Tutorial](http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/09/04/rerouting-requests-ucma-application-mspl/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to run the Application as an Administrator even though I was logged in with an Admin Account that was added to the local "RTC Server Applications" group.

I have already tried that but then my next mistake was that the Windows Forms window did not open (why is another question...) so I thought it does not work.

[This MSDN Article "Register a managed application on Lync Server 2013"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600167(v=office.15).aspx) also helped.

Comment: Running as administrator definitely should not be required. I'm running multiple MSPL server applications on normal service accounts.

Comment: It seems to be the only thing that prevented the app from working. Maybe the "Administrator" account had some permissions or groups which the "Admin" [...] account did not have.

Answer (score 0):

The message **"Queue could not be created"** usually means you need to add the account which runs your code to the **"RTC Server Applications"** group on the local machine.

Comment: This is already the case (but its called "RTC Server Applications", there is no "Local ...").

Comment: if there is no local RTC Server Application then you probably haven't run the bootstrapper. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466123.aspx